# Use subclass of a typesafe method parameter

Tags: php, oop

I try to use a subclass in a method with typesafe parameter. Don't know if I'm missing something or if the solution is to just don't make the parameter typesafe. What is the cleanest design option for this situation?

Look at following code:

```
<?php

class MyObject {
    public $name;   
}

class MySubObject extends MyObject {
    public $subProperty;    
}

abstract class Renderer {
    protected $someProperty;

    public abstract function render(MyObject $obj);
}

class RendererA extends Renderer {
    public function render(MyObject $obj) {
        return $this->someProperty . ': ' . $obj->name;
    }
}

// This is the problematic case ------|
class RendererB extends Renderer { // |
    public function render(MySubObject $obj) {
        return $this->someProperty . ': ' . $obj->name . ' ' .$obj->subProperty;
    }
}

/* EOF */
```

Comment: @deceze Well there is the reason why it's not possible but not a way around it. But as I see there's no way around.

Comment: No, not really. Your type hierarchies are not well structured. You either cannot `abstract` the `render` method or you need to rethink your type hierarchies to be more independent of one another. Currently you have two hierarchies running in parallel, if you will, with each type at a certain level only being compatible with its counterpart in the other hierarchy. That's not very sensible.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
https://github.com/symfony/Routing/blob/2.4/Router.php#L225

In this code, the Router will match a request, however it has two ways of doing this depending on the type of Matcher it has an instance of.

That case uses interfaces to differentiate between the object type, however to perform the same technique to your case try this:

```
class MyObject {
    public $name;
}

class MySubObject extends MyObject {
    public $subProperty;
}

class Renderer {
    public function render(MyObject $obj) {
        if($obj instanceof MySubObject) {
            return $this->someProperty . ': ' . $obj->name . ' ' .$obj->subProperty;
        }

        return $this->someProperty . ': ' . $obj->name;
    }
}
```

Assuming that is the only variation of functionality, you don't need an AbstractRenderer. 
Since `MySubObject` extends `MyObject` it is still type safe to use the extending class as an argument.

EDIT:

This example uses a basic form of the visitor pattern.
The Renderer essentially becomes a parent manager of multiple potential handlers.

The input is handled differently by drivers added at the configuration stage depending of the input's attributes (class in this case, but there are more advanced forms of criteria).

This example can be executed outside of namespaces.

```
interface TemplateInterface
{
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName();
}

interface DriverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param TemplateInterface $template
     * @return string
     */
    public function doRender(TemplateInterface $template);
}

class Renderer
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $drivers;

    protected $property = 'Sample Property';

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->drivers = array();
    }

    /**
     * @param TemplateInterface $template
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(TemplateInterface $template)
    {
        $class = get_class($template);

        if(false === isset($this->drivers[$class])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Renderer Driver supporting class "%s" is not present.', $class));
        }

        return sprintf('%s: %s', $this->property, $this->drivers[$class]->doRender($template));
    }

    /**
     * @param DriverInterface $driver
     * @param $class
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addDriver(DriverInterface $driver, $class)
    {
        $this->drivers[$class] = $driver;

        return $this;
    }
}

class MyTemplate implements TemplateInterface
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_template';
    }
}

class MyOtherTemplate implements TemplateInterface
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_other_template';
    }

    public function getOtherProperty()
    {
        return 'this is another property';
    }
}

class MyDriver implements DriverInterface
{
    public function doRender(TemplateInterface $template)
    {
        return $template->getName();
    }
}

class MyOtherDriver implements DriverInterface
{
    public function doRender(TemplateInterface $template)
    {
        if(false === $template instanceof MyOtherTemplate) {
            throw new InvalidaArgumentException('OtherDriver::doRender argument must be an instance of MyOtherTemplate');
        }

        return sprintf('%s %s', $template->getName(), $template->getOtherProperty());
    }
}

$renderer = new Renderer();
$renderer
    ->addDriver(new MyDriver(),      'MyTemplate')
    ->addDriver(new MyOtherDriver(), 'MyOtherTemplate')
;

echo '<pre>';

echo $renderer->render(new MyTemplate()).PHP_EOL;
echo $renderer->render(new MyOtherTemplate());
```

This is a more advanced example.
This time you don't specify the class of the template, instead you only add the driver, but this driver interface required the `supports` method be implemented.  The renderer will loop through each driver asking them if they support the template.

The first driver to return `true` will render and return the template.

```
interface DriverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param TemplateInterface $template
     * @return string
     */
    public function doRender(TemplateInterface $template);

    /**
     * @param TemplateInterface $template
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supports(TemplateInterface $template);
}

class Renderer
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $drivers;

    protected $property = 'Sample Property';

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->drivers = array();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the rendered template, or false if the template was not supported by any driver.
     *
     * @param TemplateInterface $template
     * @return string|false
     */
    public function render(TemplateInterface $template)
    {
        $class = get_class($template);

        foreach($this->drivers as $driver) {
            if($driver->supports($template)) {
                return sprintf('%s: %s', $this->property, $driver->doRender($template));
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param DriverInterface $driver
     * @param $class
     * @return $this
     */
    public function addDriver(DriverInterface $driver)
    {
        $this->drivers[] = $driver;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. Well this breaks the modularity for my renderers. Cause everybody who wants to write a new rendering method has to touch the `Renderer` class.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER I have updated my answer to hopefully better suit your modular requirements.

Comment: Okay this would solve my problem at some points but then it gets really exhausting to use my class cause you always have to define the Renderer for each type und you can't define a Renderer for each instance only for a class in common. 

But thx anyway for your huge effort :-).

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER This final update modifies the renderer and expects the driver to support a template,  essentially allowing a single driver to support more than one type of template.  If this isn't modular enough, then you may be better of encapsulating the rendering logic inside the templates themselves.  Your original approach involved a manager pattern which my examples are expanding on.

Comment: Okay so I think I'll delete the abstract class Renderer and do independent Renderers for the different classes. I think this is the best and simplest solution. That's now clear to me after this discussion. Thx very very much for your effort. I can't tick it as solved bit at least give you an upvote. Thx!

Comment: It does look a bit over-engineered, however if for example these objects were Doctrine Entities, then the rendering logic couldn't sit inside the objects themselves and expect be to SRP compliant.